# Style-components - inherit the styles and dynamic props from a styled component but not the tag

Tags: styled-components

Essentially, I am looking for a way to share a spacing styling to all components like this.

```
const Spacing = styled.div`
    padding: ${props => props.p || 0};
    padding-top: ${props => props.pt || 0};
`;
const Button = styled(Spacing)`
    background: white;
`;
```

With this example, I can inherit the dynamic padding of Spacing but the problem is it will inherit the tag. so if I use `<Button as='button' pt='2rem' > Click </Button>` I have to manually add `as=''` attribute to all inheriting component.

Is there a way to get rid of the `as=''` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

First create the styles to be inherited:

`spacing.js`

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

export const Spacing = css`
    margin-top: ${props => props.mt + "rem" || 0};
    margin-bottom: ${props => props.mb + "rem" || 0};
    margin-left: ${props => props.ml + "rem" || 0};
    margin-right: ${props => props.mr + "rem" || 0};
`;
```

`styled.button.js`

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Spacing } from "./path-to-spacing.js"

const Button = styled.button`
    ${Spacing};
    // your styles
`;
```

`usage`

```
<Button mt={4}> Click me </Button>
```